# Doctrine2 - Association mapping over two joins

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have the following associations:

Restaurant **1:n** Meal **1:n** Availability

Now i would like to have a method to get all meals which are available today. Is there a way to do that in the entity? I thought about the criteria API, but I don't know how to handle it because of the second assocation.

```
class Restaurant {
    public function getTodaysMeals() {
        $criteria = Criteria::create()
            ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('availabilities.date', '2015-10-20'));

        return $this->getMeals()->matching($criteria);
    }
}
```

**=== EDIT===**

That way I only get restaurants with a meal availability of today, but I also want the restaurants without meals.

```
class RestarantRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function find() {
        $this->createQueryBuilder('restaurant');
            ->addSelect('meals')
            ->addSelect('availabilities')
            ->leftJoin('restaurant.meals', 'meals')
            ->leftJoin('meals.availabilities', 'availabilities')
            ->where('availabilities.date', ':date');
            ->setParameter('date', '2015-10-21');

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: create a respository method, join all entities and use a where or criteria expression

Comment: usually I would do it that way, but I have to show the meals in a list of restaurants.

Comment: don't get the difference?

Comment: Ok, I didn't know, that you can iterater over a subset of an assocation if you just select that in your repository. So $restaurant->getMeals() only returns the meals i selected and not all meals of the restaurant. But now I have another problem. How can i select all restaurants with the meals of today? I will edit my question to show you my tries.